# Matplotlib - Plot line with width equivalent to a range of values, not just one single

Tags: python, matplotlib, line

What I want is quite simply adding to a normal `pyplot.plot` a horizontal line with the width equal to a range of values that I give. Preferably I also want to be able to adjust the transparency of this "block", that is the wide horizontal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to just use [`pyplot.fill_between()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.fill_between(ax.get_xlim(), min(y), max(y), color='k', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]